# Jquery Accordion header state with h3:before

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a Jquery accordion for which I would like to insert font awesome icons before the headers. Currently in my code I have:

```
.ui-accordion h3:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f0da';
    margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
    color: #000;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

which always shows the right caret before the `h3` titles on the accordion. However, I would like this to only show in default mode, `ui-state-default`, and would like to do something else when the header has been clicked, or `.ui-state-active`. When I try adding `.ui-accordion .ui-state-default h3:before` in place of `.ui-accordion h3:before`, the right caret disappears. How do I do this in CSS?

Comment: Nope, it disappears too without white space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I right remember element "ui-accordion > h3" has own class "ui-state-default" so right code should be:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-state-default:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f0da';
  margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
  color: #000;
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

also you can simple use

```
.ui-state-default:before {
  //your_code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#YOURELEMENT li a').click(function(){
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('500');
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle')
});
```

This will replace your fontawesome icon with another one on click with jquery.\
try adding the font awesome dynamically in the HTML instead of using css it makes things complicated

Comment: Adding font awesome dynamically in HTML does work, but since I have a lot of headers in my accordion I was trying to select them with CSS only.